# Python ZoneInfo not working in pyspark UDF

Tags: python, pyspark, zoneinfo

Hi Experts I am stuck with an issue where if I use the ZoneInfo from python zoneinfo package the dates are getting converted as expected, but, when I am using the same code under a spark udf it is throwing error as "No timezone found with key  Europe/Brussels". Please help me out here.
Below is the code :

**Working python code :**

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
conv_dt = datetime.strptime('2038.01.09 00:00:00', '%Y.%m.%d %H%M%S').astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Brussels'))
```

**Same code under SPARK UDF NOT working**
dataframe creation :

```
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(['2038.01.09 00:00:00'], StringType()).toDF('sampledate')
```

udf declaration :

```
def test_udf(sd):
    return datetime.strptime(sd, '%Y.%m.%d %H%M%S').astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Brussels'))
```

calling udf :

```
x = udf(test_udf, TimeStamp())
cast_df = sample_df.withColumns('sampledate',x(sample_df['sampledate']))
cast_df.show()
```

Error :
File "...lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py" ,line 24 in load_tzdata
raise

ZoneInfoNotFoundError:"No timezone found with key Europe/Brussels"

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is likely related to the way Spark UDFs work with external Python packages like zoneinfo. When you use `zoneinfo` in your Spark UDF, it needs to be available to the Spark workers. For troubleshooting, here are some steps to resolve the issue:

1. Ensure that the zoneinfo package is installed on all Spark worker nodes. You can use a tool like pip or a package manager to install it. You may need administrative access to install packages on worker nodes.
2. Make sure that the `zoneinfo` package is importable within your Spark UDF. To do this, you can include the import statement for `ZoneInfo` at the beginning of your UDF function.

You can do this by as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, TimestampType

from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ZoneInfoExample").getOrCreate()

def test_udf(sd):
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo  # Import ZoneInfo within the UDF
    return datetime.strptime(sd, '%Y.%m.%d %H%M%S').astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Brussels'))

x = udf(test_udf, TimestampType())

sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(['2038.01.09 00:00:00'], StringType()).toDF('sampledate')

cast_df = sample_df.withColumn('sampledate', x(sample_df['sampledate']))
cast_df.show()
```